# playing audio files and adjusting system volume

Tags: c++, audio, windows-vista

I'm writing a tiny music program and I'm trying to play an mp3. Right now, I have something pretty ugly but it works:

```
std::string command("cd \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\" && wmplayer /play \"D:\\music\\A Perfect Circle\\eMOTIVe\\a.mp3");

system(command.c_str());
```

Is there a better or more reliable way to do this? Also, how would one go about adjusting the master system volume?

Comment: Any info from the downvoter? I'm not looking to create a music or mp3 player. I'd just like a simple and straightforward way to play an mp3 that does not involve system(). Does any API exist which makes it as straightforward as PlaySound()?

Answer (score 1):

If there is an MP3 codec installed in Windows, you might be able to use the Win32 API `PlaySound()` function or the VCL `TMediaPlayer` component to play the file.

To set the master volumne, use the Win32 API `waveOutSetVolume()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I've created a C++ audio library named "Crosstalk".

Crosstalk is a real-time C++ audio engine that allows you to create and route audio systems.

Here's an example of how you can play your mp3 file:

```
XtSystem system;
XtMp3Decoder mp3Decoder;
XtAudioDevice audioDevice;

long md = system.addComponent(&mp3Decoder);
long ad = system.addComponent(&audioDevice);

system.connOutToIn(md,0,ad,0);
system.connOutToIn(md,1,ad,1);

mp3Decoder.loadFile("../05 Tchaikovski-Swan Lake-Scene.mp3");
mp3Decoder.play();
```

Included with Crosstalk are example Xcode and Visual Studio projects.

You can download Crosstalk and check out the API documentation and licensing details [here](http://www.adaptaudio.com/Crosstalk).

**EDIT:**

In terms of setting volume: there is a component included with Crosstalk called "XtGain" that you can wire in series between the mp3 decoder outputs and the audio device inputs. This will allow you to set the volume of the audio stream before it reaches the speakers.

**EDIT (01-12-2012):**

Crosstalk has been replaced by an open-source project called "[DSPatch](http://www.flowbasedprogramming.com)". DSPatch is essentially an upgraded version of the routing engine behind Crosstalk that is no longer limited to only audio processing. DSPatch allows you to create and route almost any type of process chain imaginable, and its free for personal AND proprietary use :)